Find Shader error source without source line
I have joined a new project and encountered an error:

Edit:
Here is the text error.
Property (_MainTex) already exists. Use SetTexture instead.

As you can see it does not have any clues on what should be fixed. It does not affect anything in the game. How would one find a starting point for investigation ?
Using Unity 2022.3.25f1

Always share error messages as text. This gives better search hits for people to be able to find this thread and share knowledge.

Searching for "Use SetTexture instead", I found this thread of similar issues, where folks found they solved it by updating their URP to the latest version, or by moving drawing code out of GUI callback functions/OnDrawGizmos. A comment on this bug report found it was due to using .mainTexture on a material that didn't have one.

@DMGregory i am more interested in the process of finding the source of this issue.
